# How to detect that "Additional log on information may be required" when connecting to a network

Tags: wifi

I have a Windows 7/8 program that manages my wifi connections in the background.  I use C#, ManagedWifi, and NETWORKLIST to do this although the language isn't important.

The program works fine except for the case when I connect to a network where the "Additional log on information may be required.  Click here to open your browser." balloon appears.

I would like to detect/intercept this and open the browser automatically within the context of my program.

Ignoring the browser part, is there an event, network property, or anything else I can use to determine that this is the case and, thus respond to it.

Many "open" hotspots do this to display the T&Cs of use and Cisco/Linksys routers that have the "guest" facility also do this.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/ask-the-wi-fi-guru-episode-40.html):

> Q: How does Windows know that “additional logon information may be
>   required?” When I connect to a hotspot, sometimes Windows pops up this
>   message. When I open my browser, the hotspot requires me to agree to
>   terms or to provide a username to access the Web like at a hotel or
>   airport. How does Windows know this? Does it know the hotspots used at
>   every hotel? – Anonymous
>
> A: It does seem almost creepy, doesn’t it, when Windows seems to know
>   that the hotspot requires a login before even you do? Thankfully the
>   answer lies in networking smarts and not anything supernatural.
>
> Whenever a Windows Vista or Windows 7 machine connects to a network,
>   it performs a few quick diagnostics. One such diagnostic is that it
>   attempts to send a Web request to the address www.msftncsi.com, and it
>   analyzes the result.
>
> If the connection is fully working, that address returns a simple text
>   file that Windows recognizes. Hotspots that require a login or a
>   terms-of-service acknowledgement capture your Web requests and
>   redirect them to the hotspot page until you are authorized. Therefore,
>   when Windows tries to retrieve this file, it fails due to hotspot
>   redirection.
>
> To be clever, Windows then performs a DNS lookup on its own website.
>   The hotspot will resolve the address, even though it won’t let you
>   access the site. In this case, Windows then concludes you are at such
>   a hotspot and pops up the “additional log on information may be
>   required” message. If the DNS lookup itself fails, Windows concludes
>   that there is actually a problem connecting to the Internet, and
>   instead displays the message “No Internet access.”

You might want to try to do the same - when a wifi connection is established, try to connect to www.msftncsi.com, and if it fails, try a DNS lookup.